# how do i return the resutls of a Joined query using php?

Tags: php, subquery

The Query is as follows:

```
  SELECT v2.video_id
    FROM `VideoTags` AS v1
    JOIN `VideoTags` AS v2 USING ( tag_id )
   WHERE v1.video_id =1
     AND v1.video_id <> v2.video_id
GROUP BY v2.video_id
ORDER BY COUNT( * ) DESC
```

i am trying to get related videos when i run this query in phpmyadmin it returns the correct result set however when i try to write this using php and echo out the results i get no values returned the code im using for the query is:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT v2.video_id FROM `VideoTags` AS v1 JOIN `VideoTags` AS v2 USING ( tag_id ) WHERE v1.video_id =1 AND v1.video_id <> v2.video_id GROUP BY v2.video_id ORDER BY COUNT( * ) DESC"); 

$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );

echo "ID ".$row['video_id'];
```

im sure its something simple i just cant seem to figure it out? if someone could please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using this query:
`SELECT v2.video_id as v2id FROM VideoTags AS v1 JOIN VideoTags AS v2 USING ( tag_id ) WHERE v1.video_id =1 AND v1.video_id <> v2.video_id GROUP BY v2.video_id ORDER BY COUNT( * ) DESC`

and then

`echo "ID ".$row['v2id'];`

Comment: this still returns no results any ideas?

Comment: i thought about ambigious names... that was the idea

Comment: This seems to have solved the issue there are two tables with the same col name video_id. i have put this into a while loop to echo out each of the values how would i now push this in to variable so i could use it in a sub-query

Comment: sorry i'm trying to use this result in another query so i need to store the values in a variable as a comma separated array. so i can use them in this query: SELECT * FROM videos WHERE video_id IN (value, value, value); hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0):

It returns an array so you can loop it out

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT v2.video_id FROM `VideoTags` AS v1 JOIN `VideoTags` AS v2 USING ( tag_id ) WHERE v1.video_id =1 AND v1.video_id <> v2.video_id GROUP BY v2.video_id ORDER BY COUNT( * ) DESC"); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    echo "ID " . $row[0] . "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it won't let me comment on Trikks's answer, but he's basically correct except for one thing, so I would give it to him. Instead of $row[0], you will want $row['video_id']; (according to the example provided). I changed the echo to single quotes since you're not using variables inside the echo and single quotes are faster than double quotes.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT v2.video_id FROM `VideoTags` AS v1 JOIN `VideoTags` AS v2 USING ( tag_id ) WHERE v1.video_id =1 AND v1.video_id <> v2.video_id GROUP BY v2.video_id ORDER BY COUNT( * ) DESC"); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))
{
    echo 'ID ' . $row['video_id'] . '<br />';
}
```

EDIT: Also, if you're not getting any values returned, I would check that you're using the right key using `print_r(array_key($row));`:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT v2.video_id FROM `VideoTags` AS v1 JOIN `VideoTags` AS v2 USING ( tag_id ) WHERE v1.video_id =1 AND v1.video_id <> v2.video_id GROUP BY v2.video_id ORDER BY COUNT( * ) DESC"); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))
{
    print_r(array_key($row));
    echo 'ID ' . $row['video_id'] . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: for some reason i'm still getting no values returned?? what should the print_r(array_key($row)); return?

Comment: It should be `print_r(array_keys($row));` (note the plural keys), and it should produce a list of all the keys in the array. `print_r($row)` should also work, and will show the keys AND values.